How access Azure APIs
I am trying to access the Azure APIs, using postman, for example https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01 but completely lost with MS documentation. I went through some threads here and they talk about sending some parameters in the body, such as:

client_id=  &client_secret=  &grant_type=client_credentials
&resource=

How/Where can I get those details. Is it somewhere in Azure portal?

Is this below solution works for you?

Hi Brian, not sure I understand which solution you re refering to? I cant see any solution here. The only thing I can see is from user23826139 which is a general description to which I responded. I visited tenant and subscription pages in my azure portal but no indication how to get the needed details

To get the client_id and client secret for fetching https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01 query  you need to register application in Microsoft Entra ID and generate access token.  Go to Microsoft Entra ID --> App registration

Thanks Brian, I created an app in app registration, generated client secret, switched to postman, used POST with url https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01   then entered in body the 3 keys client_id, client_secret and grant_type. I get an error message as follows "error": {
"code": "MissingSubscription",
"message": "The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant level resource provider."
}

I added subscriptionID to params but it did not help

No need to add subscription_id, Shall I post an answer?

Yes please go ahead

Posted an answer

I did accept Patrik response


To access this API query
GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01

Initially, I registered Single Tenant Microsoft Entra ID application
Go to portal --> Microsoft Entra ID -->App registration

Added and granted API permission of Azure Service Management like below:

Also, I added RBAC role of Reader to Service Principal at Subscription level:

Now, Added Client Secret:

Now, Generate access token using Postman or ThunderClient(VS Code Extension) with below parameters:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id = <client_id>
client_secret= <client secret>
grant_type = client_credentials
scope = https://management.azure.com/.default



Now use this generated access token to fetch the below query:
GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01

Reference:
Tenants-List
Azure-RBAC Roles

Yeees Patrik, this worked like a charm, so many thanks. But tell me, this works fine for almost 10 APIs regarding RGs, Advisor Recommandation but I imagine that for other services not in "Azure Services management" category or other Azure services the way to call them might be different. I have already visited the link you provided Tenants-List but it does not explain things as you did in your wonderful response. So many thanks again

what I wanted to say is about mainly for the SCOPE values, where I can find a list of all scopes/resources to query?

@eliassal Glad to know, it works for you!

@eliassal  At which scope level means at Subscription or Resource, or which query you want to use? Could you please elaborate further?

you would enter your credentials for these:
client_id= &client_secret= &grant_type=client_credentials &resource=

it depends on what azure services/resources you're trying to connect to.
go to that resource in the azure portal, and check out connections or access to that resouce under info or connections and enter them.
Different azure services have slightly different look, so you'll have to dig around.

Dear @user23826139, as I visited tenant properties as well as subscription, no indication on generating any code on those pages, as I said I need to run the APIs  https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01 or  https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2022-12-01. I am the super admin of the portal

@eliassal Are you still looking for the solution?
